# Play framework - java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: ajax, playframework, nio, playframework-2.1

Here is the scenario.

I am using Play framework. Inside a given handler, the play framework calls my API webservice and returns the API response to the client. The client is calling the handler through an Ajax call. Sometimes the response comes fine but often i am seeing error response on the client side. Checking the logs of play framework, i see a java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException.

I am using Play 2.1.1.
My API Webservice is running on localhost:8888. Play framework is running on 9000. 
The API service response is correct. Play frameworks also executes the Callback correctly as i can see the logs. The error happens after the ok() call has been made from Play.

Here are the error logs for a failed request -

```
[debug] application - find...
[debug] application - id = 647110558
[trace] c.jolbox.bonecp - Check out connection [9 leased]
[trace] c.jolbox.bonecp - Check in connection [9 leased]
[debug] application - socialUser = SocialUser(UserId(647110558,facebook),Arvind,Batra,Arvind Batra,Some(arvindbatra@gmail.com),null,AuthenticationMethod(oauth2),null,Some(OAuth2Info(CAAHNVOUuNZAEBAMa3CPLUEsZA2Tp5xWGXylO9HggBY0TCfwsIn4iGUdlRMpuNPLxYcObKO5ZBZCU0ghS9ymHZC3s9YXpsfPix9AM1EhNyETvDR85HHYg8j7JO0h2WzGZBsKJdbFPhPmkD6ZBZAq6KTT8RLSQrmpfnHQZD,null,null,null)),null)
[info] application - Calling interest for fff
[info] application - user is not null
[trace] c.jolbox.bonecp - Check out connection [9 leased]
[info] application - interest=fff, userInfo:models.EBUser@14a420e1
[info] application - http://localhost:8888/api/add_interest/1/fff
[debug] c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyAsyncHttpProvider - Using cached Channel [id: 0x9d1dee2d, /127.0.0.1:50316 => localhost/127.0.0.1:8888]
 for uri http://localhost:8888/api/add_interest/1/fff
    [debug] c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyAsyncHttpProvider - 
Using cached Channel [id: 0x9d1dee2d, /127.0.0.1:50316 => localhost/127.0.0.1:8888]
 for request 
DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
GET /api/add_interest/1/fff HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*    User-Agent: NING/1.0

[debug] c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyAsyncHttpProvider -

Request DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
GET /api/add_interest/1/fff HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NING/1.0

Response DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: true)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2013 12:14:40 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[debug] c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyConnectionsPool - Adding uri: http://localhost:8888 for channel [id: 0x9d1dee2d, /127.0.0.1:50316 => localhost/127.0.0.1:8888]
[info] application - {"status":"success"}
[info] application - {"status":"ok","exists":false}
[trace] play - Sending simple result: SimpleResult(200, Map(Content-Type -> application/json; charset=utf-8, Set-Cookie -> ))
[debug] play - java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
[trace] application - Exception caught in Netty
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:409) ~[netty.jar:na]
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:127) ~[netty.jar:na]
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99) ~[netty.jar:na]
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36) ~[netty.jar:na]
  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725) ~[netty.jar:na]
  at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71) ~[netty.jar:na]
[debug] c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyConnectionsPool - Entry count for : http://localhost:8888 : 2
```

Here is my sample code -

```
  public static Result addInterestCallback(WS.Response response) {
    if (response == null) {

      return badRequest();
    }
    ObjectNode result = (ObjectNode) response.asJson();
    try {
      Logger.info(result.toString());

      if (result.has("status")) {
        String status = result.get("status").getTextValue();
        if(status.equals("error")) {
          result.put("error", "Oops, cannot process your request. Sorry.");
          Logger.info("error");
          return badRequest(result);
        }
        else if(status.equals("exists")) {
          result.put("exists",true);
        }
        else {
          result.put("exists",false);
        }
        result.put("status", "ok");
      } else {
        //do something
        Logger.info("result has no status");
      }
      Logger.info(result.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ok(result);

  }
  @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
  @SecureSocial.UserAwareAction
  public static Result addInterest() {

    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    String interestName = json.findPath("interestName").getTextValue();
    Logger.info("Calling interest for " + interestName);

    Identity user = (Identity) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);
    if (user == null) {
      ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
      result.put("error", "requires-login");
      Http.Context ctx = Http.Context.current();
      ctx.flash().put("error", play.i18n.Messages.get("securesocial.loginRequired"));
      result.put("redirect", RoutesHelper.login().absoluteURL(ctx.request(), IdentityProvider.sslEnabled()));
      return ok(result);
    }
    Logger.info("user is not null");
    if(interestName == null) {
      ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
      result.put("error", "Empty input");
      return badRequest(result);
    }
    //get user
    EBUser ebUser = Application.getEBUser();
    Logger.info("interest="+interestName+", userInfo:" + ebUser.toString());

    //Call addInterst API.
    String apiEndpoint = Play.application().configuration().getString(AppConstants.EB_API_ENDPOINT);
    String url = "";
    try {
      url = apiEndpoint + "add_interest/" + ebUser.getId() + "/" + URLEncoder.encode(interestName, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
      result.put("error", "Cant parse interest properly");
      Logger.info("error " + result.toString());
      return badRequest(result);
    }

    Logger.info(url);
    Promise<WS.Response> promiseOfAPI = WS.url(url).get();
    Promise<Result>  promiseOfResult =  promiseOfAPI.map(
        new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
          @Override
          public Result apply(WS.Response response) throws Throwable {
            return addInterestCallback(response);
          }
        });

    return async(promiseOfResult);
}
```

Name of Handler is addInterest.

Any pointers on what could be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

> java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

This means *you* have closed the channel and then continued to use it.

Comment: Right, for example the browser is closed now and the server still sends a message to the disappeared client.

Comment: @Twistleton Wrong. That would cause a 'connection reset'. This one is caused by the application closing its own channel.